# Fail to build k3s from source on tag v1.18.9+k3s1

Tags: git, k3s

I clone k3s source from https://github.com/k3s-io/k3s.git, and want to build version=v1.18.9+k3s1. but I get error as bellow

```
Tagged version 'v1.18.10+k3s1' does not match expected version 'v1.18.9[+-]*'
```

I am confused. I really run `git checkout v1.18.9+k3s1` and then run `make`.

I dive into the source code, and find the error comes from running `./script/version.sh`, which checks version.

In `./script/version.sh`, there one line code as below

```
GIT_TAG=$(git tag -l --contains HEAD | head -n 1)
```

then I run `git tag -l --contains HEAD | head -n 1` and get `GIT_TAG=v1.18.10+k3s1`.

Why not tag `v1.18.9+k3s1`?

**So the problem become, when I checkout tag version by `git checkout v1.18.9+k3s1`, but different to the result of `git tag -l --contains HEAD | head -n 1`**

What's happening ? Anyone can help me ?

here is the git log, which shows head is at tag  `v1.18.9+k3s1`

```
commit 630bebf94b9dce6b8cd3d402644ed023b3af8f90 (HEAD, tag: v1.18.9-rc1+k3s1, tag: v1.18.9+k3s1)
Merge: b9542ef001 44139e60f5
Author: Menna Elmasry <65324011+MonzElmasry@users.noreply.github.com>
Date:   Thu Sep 17 03:22:57 2020 +0200

    Merge pull request #2268 from MonzElmasry/v1.18.9-k3s1
    
    k3s v1.18.9-k3s1

commit 44139e60f5139cc0dd89550fa7b56bb68560ee27
Author: MonzElmasry <menna.elmasry@rancher.com>
Date:   Thu Sep 17 00:40:19 2020 +0200

    [WIP] v1.18.9-k3s1
    
    Signed-off-by: MonzElmasry <menna.elmasry@rancher.com>
```

Comment: `GIT_TAG=$(git tag -l --contains HEAD | head -n 1)` depends on the order-of-output of the corresponding tags, and is thus a bad strategy. Whether this is your problem, I don't know, but whoever did this should consider using `git describe --contains`, though this requires careful attention to tags. Failing that, adding `--sort=<key>` could help: that will avoid depending on `tags.sort` and/or the local collation settings.

Comment: @torek Thank you, I get it.